# protractor execution stack between specs describe and it

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm confused with how JS is executing the spec files in protractor. In my conf.js I have 2 specs ['spec1','spec2']

spec1:

```
 "use strict";
    console.log('1');

    describe('A', function(){
        console.log('2');

        it('B', function(){
            console.log('3');
        });
    });
```

spec2:

```
 "use strict";
    console.log('4');

    describe('C', function(){
        console.log('5');

        it('D', function(){
            console.log('6');
        });
    });
```

when running the test the output is:

```
1
2
4
5
Started
Spec started
3
.
  A
    ✓ B

6
.  C
    ✓ D
```

why is it not in the order of 123456?

Comment: because the `it` blocks will be added to control flow, the other ones execute right after `onPrepare` completes and just before the spec starts.  The two files are loaded up and onPrepare finished, so it executes those four numbers in the order of specs as expected, `1, 2, 4, 5`, then starts the spec and prints the next two out also in order of the specs

Comment: interesting..does disabling the control flow matter? Because I do have SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false specified in my conf.js

Comment: Yes it does matter.  Protractor (or more specifically, webdriver) uses the control flow to maintain a queue of pending promises.  It's what allows your code to execute asynchronously without you explicitly writing it asynchronously.  I'm not really sure why you would disable that SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER, their docs indicate that this method will not be deprecated for a long time (at least 2 more major Node releases)

Comment: but how can the it() block be added to the CF if the CF is disabled? The above code is the result with CF disabled. Also I thought only promises are pushed to the CF and the it() block is not a promise? I'm still confused.